Sparking between pins of an electrolytic capacitor
I just replaced a faulty 22 uF 400 V electrolytic capacitor with an 33 uF 450 V inside of a 5.1 V DC power adapter. It supplies power for an old modem/router.
At first, everything looks fine. The modem powers up and it's working. But periodically, there a spark between the two "legs" of the capacitor. When it happens, the modem shutoffs and reboots again.
I read some threads similar to my situation that people say it's "OK" or even better to replace a faulty capacitor with another one which has little bigger capacitance.
What could be causing that sparking behavior?
Faulty capacitor (click for larger image):

New capacitor (click for larger image):

Spark location (click for larger image):


Could be a component selection issue; just replacing a component with one that's 50% bigger is never a good idea unless you have a good understanding of the circuit. The rest of the circuit could be faulty as well given that the original capacitor failed. Or it could be a big solder blob.

There should never be a spark between the legs of that capacitor.
I'm going to make a guess that you've used a non-electronic grade solder with acid flux and it's producing a conductive path which will destroy the board in time.
In any case, there's something like a contamination there that is not right. Clean the board thoroughly with 99% isopropanol and an old toothbrush, both sides, around the high voltage parts.
The other possibility I see is that your soldering is poor or there is an intermittent connection from damage removing the part. Inspect it with a magnifier if necessary under copious light and wiggle the capacitor a bit (gently) to see if a pad is broken from the traces. If the pad moves and the trace doesn't, then jumper it.

I just add another picture where the spark occurs. I had cleaned the board with Isopropanol. But I'm going to clean the board again thoroughly to see if there is improvement.

You're right. one of the capacitor leg is detached. I can see it's moving if I'm wiggling the capacitor.

Update: I just resoldered the detached leg and cleaned the board until the new swap stays white. So far so good. Many thanks. You should work as a forensic detective to investigate any incident related to electricity or electronics. LOL. Thank again.
